# Spring AOP - advise super class method not overridden in subclass

Tags: spring, aop, spring-aop

```
public abstract class AService<T> {
  public T needsToBeAdvised(T param) {
    T result = doSomething(param);
    return result;
  }
}

@Service
public class BService extends AService<B> {
  @Override
  public T needsToBeAdvised(T param) {
    return super.needsToBeAdvised(param);
  }
}

@Service
public class CService extends AService<C> {}

// (B & C implement an interface AType)

@Component
@Aspect
public class MyAspect {
  @Pointcut("execution(* package.AService+.needsToBeAdvised(*))")
  private void aNeedToBeAdvised() {}

  @AfterReturning(pointcut="aNeedToBeAdvised()", returning="param")
  public void interceptNeedsToBeAdvised(JoinPoint joinPoint, AType param) {
    // some action
  }
}
```

Given this setup:

```
bService.needsToBeAdvised(bParam) //is intercepted
```

but,

```
cService.needsToBeAdvised(cParam) //is NOT.
```

How do I achieve this without overriding `needsToBeAdvised()` in `CService`?

EDIT:

I should add that `BService` and `CService` are both in the same package.

If I change my point-cut to the following:

```
@Pointcut("execution(* package.CService.needsToBeAdvised(*))")

cService.needsToBeAdvised(cParam) //is still not intercepted
```

The only way it works is if I override `needsTobeAdvised()` in `CService`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are all services in the same package? Given from your example code, I suspect `AService` and `BService` to be in the `package` package, but `CService` to be in another package. If services indeed are in different packages, you have some options:

- Move so that they are in the same package
- Change you pointcut to be more generic, e.g. `"execution(* *.A+.needsToBeAdvised(*))`
- Add more pointcuts

Comment: Thanks for your response. They are in the same package. See edit above.